# control reaches end of non-void function error

Tags: c

I just started practicing in Hackerrank and have encountered this error.

The Question is to find the greatest among 4 numbers using a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

void main()
{

    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

}
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
     if(a>b&& a>c && a>d) 

       return (a);
       else if(a<b&& b>c && b>d)
       return (b);
       else if(c>b&& a<c && c>d)
       return (c);
       else if(d>b&& d>c && a<d)
       return (d);
}
```

Comment: wat error are you encountering/getting ? post the error

Comment: is it the return type of `main`?

Comment: There are cases that don't return. Consider when all arguments are equal.

Comment: Aside: remove the `else` keywords which serve no purpose after a `return`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hmm. They make the code more readable in my opinion. And removing them does not solve the error, does it?

Comment: @Yunnosch that's why it was an 'aside'. Just a matter of style I suppose, IMO there is less clutter.

Comment: @WeatherVane I missed the "aside", sorry. And opinions divide. I accept yours and keep mine. :-)

Comment: Its solved I just had to remove else if at the last condition and type only "else"

Comment: As an aside `void main(){...}` is not one of the recognized, portable signatures of the `main` functrion.  Suggest you use `int main(void) {...return 0;}`.)

Comment: Plenty of "asides" already. Here's mine: Your conditions are too complicated and will miss some maximum values even after you've fixed the compiler warning. For example, `max_of_four(1, 2, 2, 1) == 1`. Do it the straightforward way: `int max = a; if (b > max) max 0 b; if (c > max) max = c; inf (max > d) max = d; return max;`.That's three comparisons. You code does that just for one case!

Comment: @MOehm Interesting. Could you elaborate how `max_of_four(1, 2, 2, 1)` results in 1? For that case I see the end of function without return. I'd then expect the unreliable thing that the last calculation/evaluatoin is returned which I think is a boolean false, i.e. 0.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Hm. I seem to have read in a comment that OP fixed the problem by removing the last condition. In that case -- only making the last `else if`an `if`, but not adjusting the `<`to `<=` -- I get the wrong answer in the case above. I adimit that fixing one thing but not the other was not right. Anyway, my principal point still holds: The code is too complicated for what it wants to chieve.

Comment: @MOehm I see that comment. If you were referring to that solution, then I am with you. A misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah, I've found that comment now, too. It wasn't under your answer. A misunderstanding, yes, but on my part. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get to the end of this function without seeing a return.
That is what the compiler is telling you.
And here is why.

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
     if(a>b&& a>c && a>d) 
       return (a);
     else if(a<b&& b>c && b>d)
       return (b);
     else if(c>b&& a<c && c>d)
       return (c);
     else if(d>b&& d>c && a<d)
       return (d);
     /* so what if none of above applies? e.g. if some are equal? */
}
```

The goal can be achieved by replacing all `>` by `>=`, all `<` by `<=` and deleting the last `if()`, i.e. turn the `else if` into an `else`. Even if the largest number occurs twice or four times, you will find it that way.